# Black lines on either side of video in PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

When I embed a video (mp4) into a pdf in Acrobat Pro to make an interactive PDF, I am getting black lines down the left and right sides of the video when I play the video.
When I scale the video, I get black lines on the top and bottom.

Any ideas how I can stop these from appearing?

Comment: I have no experience with videos in pdfs, but this also happens with images sometimes. Is it possible to place the video inside a clipping path and crop the edges a tiny bit? Or could you perhaps add a white stroke to the containing box to cover the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There's typically a checkbox in the Add Multimedia dialogue for snap-to-proportions which *should* make the windowing for the video exactly on the correct bounds; there's also a checkbox area (under advanced options) for whether there is a border drawn around the video or not, and if yes, the stroke weight.

Where this lives and how it looks is *extremely* dependent upon *which version* of Acrobat Pro you're using (IX, XI, DC) so it's not worth the time for me to detail the where-in-the-menu-hierarchy-it-lives stuff - but I can tell you I just tested on my machine (Win 10, Acrobat XI Pro) and had no trouble controlling this parameter.

Hope this helps.